# How can i link the JSON Schema to my JSON to validate the JSON against?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am new to JSON Schema and read that what is JSON Schema and so on.. But didn't get that how can I link the JSON Schema to JSON to validate against that JSON Schema. Can anyone explain?

Please can anyone explain to me in easy words that how can I link the JSON Schema to JSON file to check and validate the JSON file Data against the JSON Schema?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the json.net tag, I am concluding that you intent to do the JSON data validation against json data in C#.

It's very simple / straightforward.

1. You parse the schema into a `JsonSchema` object instance.
2. Parse the json data into a `JObject` object instance.
3. Invoke the `IsValid` method of the `JObject` instance variable (with the parsed `JsonSchema` object instance as a parameter). This method invocation will return a `bool` - `true` if valid, `false` if invalid.

Here are 2 complete examples

#### Schema is Valid Example

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
// true
```

#### Schema is Ialid Example

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': null,
  'hobbies': ['Invalid content', 0.123456789]
}");

IList<string> messages;
bool valid = person.IsValid(schema, out messages);
// false
// Invalid type. Expected String but got Null. Line 2, position 21.
// Invalid type. Expected String but got Float. Line 3, position 51.
```

#### Source: **newtonsoft.com** / [Validating JSON with JSON Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm)

**UPDATE 1:** It looks like the schema validation has been moved out into it's own Library / Nuget Package. Note, however, that this one is not completely free to use in commercial project (if that's your situation). The Pricing page has more info.

#### [Json.NET Schema - Complete JSON Schema framework for .NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)

#### Also there's an online json schema validator here => http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/